# Iterate through odd members of collection in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

What is an efficient way to iterate through only the odd members of a collection in Scala, based on index position?

Given this list:

```
val fruits: List[String] = List("apples", "oranges", "pears", "bananas")
```

I want to to skip apples and pears, and process oranges and bananas.  Thanks!

**Update based on responses given:**

Wow, each of the top three answers has merit. I originally meant the word "efficient" from a Scala Collections syntax perspective, and I was really just looking for a slick way to create the sublist for subsequent iteration. @Senia does a good job introducing the sliding() function, great for this particular use case, but I also like @Brian's more generalized approach using zipWithIndex().

However, when I consider the actual wording of the question as originally asked and the computational efficiency of @sourcedelica's response, I think he takes the prize for this one.

Comment: None of the answers so far interate through the odd members. Instead, they produce a list of the odd members (which can then be iterated over, of course). There must be a simple way of directly iterating ove them, though?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a way to directly iterate over the odd ones:

```
val fruits: List[String] = List("apples", "oranges", "pears", "bananas")
//> fruits  : List[String] = List(apples, oranges, pears, bananas)

val oddFruitsIterator = 
  Iterator.from(1, 2).takeWhile(_ < fruits.size).map(fruits(_))
//> oddFruits  : Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

oddFruitsIterator.foreach(println)                      
//> oranges
//> bananas
```

If it is a large collection and/or of you are doing lots of iterations then you will want to consider converting it to an `IndexedSeq` first so the `fruits(_)` is O(1).  For example:

```
val fruitsIs = fruits.toIndexedSeq
val oddFruits = Iterator.from(1, 2).takeWhile(_ < fruitsIs.size).map(fruitsIs(_))
```

Note that the iterator itself is separate from the collection that it is iterating over.  Here is another example that makes that more clear:

```
scala> val oddSeqIterator = 
   (seq: Seq[String]) => Iterator.from(1, 2).takeWhile(_ < seq.size).map(seq(_))
oddSeqIterator: Seq[String] => Iterator[String] = <function1>

scala> val fruits: List[String] = List("apples", "oranges", "pears", "bananas")
fruits: List[String] = List(apples, oranges, pears, bananas)

scala> oddSeqIterator(fruits)
res0: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

scala> res0.foreach(println)
oranges
bananas
```

Answer (score 18):

```
scala> List("apples", "oranges", "pears", "bananas").drop(1).sliding(1, 2).flatten.toList
res0: List[java.lang.String] = List(oranges, bananas)
```

Answer (score 17):

```
val fruits: List[String] = List("apples", "oranges", "pears", "bananas")

fruits.zipWithIndex.filter(_._2 % 2 == 1).map(_._1)

res0: List[String] = List(oranges, bananas)
```

zipWithIndex pairs each element in List with an index giving:

`List[(String, Int)] = List((apples,0), (oranges,1), (pears,2), (bananas,3))`

filter the odd elements with `filter(_._2 % 2 == 1)` giving:

`List[(String, Int)] = List((oranges,1), (bananas,3))`

map the List[(String, Int)] to just List[String] by taking the first element of each tuple with `.map(_._1)` giving:

`List[String] = List(oranges, bananas)`

Comment: Alternatively, whenever you have a `filter` followed by a `map`, you can combine them using `collect`, eg, `fruits.zipWithIndex.collect{case(item,idx) if idx % 2 == 1 => item}`

Comment: very nice post this one in deed !  Scala collection package justifies its usage in distributed computing.

Answer (score 1):

I would propose another method, using recursion, which seems to make as little operations as possible in my opinion even if it is less fancy than other solutions.

```
def iterateOdd(myList:List[String]):List[String] = myList match{
  case _::odd::tail => odd::iterateOdd(tail)
  case _ => Nil
}
```

Or, if you just want to process odd members

```
def iterateOdd(myList:List[String]):Unit = myList match{
  case _::odd::tail => println(odd); iterateOdd(tail)
  case _ =>   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another alternative, based on a combination of [`List::grouped`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#grouped(size:Int):Iterator[Repr]) in order to partition items by pair (which provides an easy way to access items at odd possitions) and [`Iterator::collect`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/collection/Iterator.html#collect[B](pf:PartialFunction[A,B]):Iterator[B]) in order to handle collections with odd length:

```
// val fruits = List("apples", "oranges", "pears", "bananas", "tomatoes")
fruits.grouped(2).collect { case a :: b => b }.toList
// List("oranges", "bananas")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think tailrec would be a better option because id does not need any stack and it is O(1):

```
def f(arr:List[Int]):List[Int] = {
@tailrec
  def loop(source:List[Int],destination:List[Int]):List[Int]= source match {
    case _::odd::tail => loop(tail,destination :+ odd)
    case _ => destination
  }
  loop(arr,List())
}
```

Answer (score -1):

- I have another approach to solve this type of problem.
- We can take advantage of List.range(start,end) method.

List.range(0,5) will give List(0,1,2,3,4)

- We can generate List of indexes and we can filter them

  scala> val fruits: List[String] = List("apples", "oranges", "pears", "bananas")

  scala> List.range(0,fruits.length).filter(_%2!=0).map(x=>fruits(x))

  res0: List[String] = List(oranges, bananas)

Comment: List.range(0,5) will give List(0,1,2,3,4)